# 17.10 64 bit on HP 250 G4 problem of "Unknown Display" resolution 1024 x 768

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10, display-resolution, intel

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 64 bit on HP 250 G4 notebook.  All updated and upgraded.

It has an "Intel hD Graphics" adapter but Intel's support is until 17.04

The main problem here is; the External Monitor ( 22" and I know it can support Full HD resolution 1920 x 1080 pixels ).

The monitor is "Unknown Display" and it can only support "1024 x 768"

.

How can I make it 1980x1080 permanently ?

Thanks for your help from now on.

Orionsbelt

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no-one answered in 3 days after I post it. I believe there are many question posters and too few answerers. But I have solved my problem and now I want to share the solution.

First, you cannot get rid of "Unknown Display" easily, it's a lot of complex work to do with a newly created 10-monitor.conf ( in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d ), but -- here is the good news -- you can make it work with whichever resolution you like.

Ubuntu 17.10 64bit comes with WAYLAND -- device XWAYLAND0. With WAYLAND you cannot change resolution dynamically to 1920 x 1080 or whatever you like.

XRandR cannot change it if it's WAYLAND. So first you need to disable it by :

```
nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

find and uncomment "WaylandEnable=false"

Then save and exist and reboot your Ubuntu.  This will disable Wayland and enable you to change the resolution by XRandR.

You need to see your Graphic Output Device's name by

```
xrandr -q
```

Then you need to get your ModeLine -- it may change from computer to computer. So you can get it by:

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

It may be something like :

Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

Then add the lines to add 1920 x 1080 resolution to your profile by:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

and adding 2 lines at the end of the file :

```
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then save and exit. The last line will be added to the X startup.

```
nano /etc/X11/Xsession
```

and add this line to the very end before "exit 0"

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

( remember to change "DP-2" with your own Device-name ! )

Then save and exit. And reboot the computer.

Then the resolution is automatically 1920 x 1080 pixels.

There might be slight changes in time with the version-changes in Ubuntu. You'll discover the ways to do it with some web-research.

Good luck.